# How to add location substring to all the links in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the substring from the url and use it next to all the links in the page,so that i can pass the same substring to all the pages using javascript.

here is what i have tried

```
<a href="home.html?'+location.search.substring(1)+'">home.html</a>
```

but its not working for me. how can i do this?

Comment: you can't use javascript directly in attributes most html attributes - how is the html written? can you use jquery?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, do you have sample code please?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
$('a').attr('href', function() {
    return this.href + '?' + location.search.substring(1);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('a').attr('href', function() {
        return this.href + '?' + location.search.substring(1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="home.html">HOME</a> | 
<a href="about.html">ABOUT</a> |
<a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery:

```
$.each($('a'), function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr('href') + '?' + location.search.substring(1);
    $(this).attr('href', attr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a#someId').attr('href', 'home.html?' + location.search.substring(1)); 
});
```

You should add either a class or an ID to the links to get a good selector.

Comment: Note that this solution update the links only when the page is loaded and not if the url is changed later on..

Answer (score 0):

In vanillaJs this would look something like:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
[].forEach.call(links , function(link) {
  link.href = link.href + location.search.substring(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add Substring to links</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('a').each(function(index,value){
    var newhref = ( $(this).attr('href') + '?' + window.location.search.substring(1) );

    $(this).attr('href', newhref);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```